# Get the string inside [] using PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have below content in a file, I want to change the format of the string

```
$reg = xyz.abc.1234['xyz']

$regxyz = xyz.abc.1234['abc']
```

I am able to replace the format but I am not able to get the value of a string inside `['']`

```
$path = path/to/file

$content = (Select-String -Path $path -Pattern "xyz.abc.1234\['.*'\]").Matches.Value

foreach ($string in $content) {

    #$value = "Revision"

    $string -Replace "xyz.abc.1234\['.*'\]", """`${$value}""" 
}
```

Expected Result is

```
$reg = "${xyz}"

$regxyz = "${abc}"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75044759/1701026? Btw, if you want verify the preceding `xyz.abc.1234` you need group that to exclude it from the results (and [escape the dots](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html): `xyz\.abc\.1234`)

Comment: @iRon, No that was not worked in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following pattern:

```
'xyz\.abc\.1234\[''(\w+)''\]'
```

The `(...)` parentheses around `\w+` will "capture" the string inside the quotes in inside `[...]`, at which point we can refer to it in the substitute string as `$1`:

```
$string -Replace 'xyz\.abc\.1234\[''(\w+)''\]', '"$${$1}"'
```